# PlotLegend disappears if Plot is used with ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, bugs, legending

Working some charts on V10,  I discovered that `PlotLegends` disappears if used together with `ColorFunction` inside `ListPlot` or `Plot`. Here is one example for `Plot`:

```
Plot[Sinc[x],{x,0,10},PlotLegends->{"Teste"},PlotStyle->Thick]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sinc[x],{x,0,10}, PlotLegends->{"Teste"}, PlotStyle->Thick
     ,ColorFunction->(ColorData["AvocadoColors"][#2]&)
]
```

[image]

The same problem to ListPlot.

I'm on Mac using V10. Anyone else confirm this?

Comment: same here. Also on OS X

Comment: Does it work in 9? I wouldn't have thought so. Legend lines tend to be mono colour. `ColorData["AvocadoColors"]` precludes this.

Comment: A legend is produced in 9 but of course it doesn't actually match the colours used in the plot. So I'd class that as a bug in 9 and this as a fix in 10.

Comment: You can use `ColorFunction -> (Red &)`, and have the same problem. I just tested in the company machine (still V9) and It works. It's a V10 bug.

Comment: So you are expecting the legend line to be a colour gradient? What does (ColorData["AvocadoColors"][#2]&) give you on your V9? Mine gives a legend with a different colour line

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I don't know. Maybe to be the average or center color. In my windows V9 it's dark blue. For me It's ok if it reproduce V9 behavior.

Comment: I guess I see it as a bug in V9. If you have a gradient colour line in a plot you shouldn't have a monocolour line in the legend. Therefore for me the absence of the legend in 10 makes more sense. just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use `gradient color schemes` for `LineLegend`

```
Plot[{Sinc[x], Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["NeonColors"][x]],
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend["NeonColors", {"Teste", "Tuste", "Taste"}],
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

```
?? LineLegend
```

will reveal some hints:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

A work-around:

```
plt = Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
           ColorFunction -> (ColorData["AvocadoColors"][#2] &), ImageSize -> 400];
legend = Row[{Graphics[plt[[1]], AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 30], "Teste"}];
Legended[plt, legend]
```

[image]

In Version 10, one can use `PlotTheme->"Sparkline"` to create the thumbnail legend:

```
legend2=Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
            PlotLegends->"Teste",
            ColorFunction -> (ColorData["AvocadoColors"][#2] &),
            PlotTheme->"Sparkline",AspectRatio->1, ImageSize->30]
```

... and another:

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 400,
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["AvocadoColors"][#2] &),
  PlotLegends -> Row[{Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}},
              VertexColors -> {ColorData["AvocadoColors"][0],
                               ColorData["AvocadoColors"][2]}]}], "Teste"}, Spacer[5]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I appreciate that this is a question with philosophical and technical dimensions about automation. Like kguler a work  around:

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["AvocadoColors"][#2] &), 
 ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend["AvocadoColors", LegendMarkers -> None, 
   LegendLabel -> Style["Teste", Black], LabelStyle -> White, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {3, 150}]]
```

[image]

I made the legend vertical just to match the scaling by 'y' value.

Or:

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["AvocadoColors"][#2] &), 
 ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend["AvocadoColors", LegendLayout -> "Row", 
   LegendMarkers -> None, LegendLabel -> Style["Teste", Black], 
   LabelStyle -> White, LegendMarkerSize -> {150, 3}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you want same legend as in plot1, maybe also some round way like this:

```
p1 = First@Last@Plot[Sinc[x];, {x, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"Teste"}];
Row[{Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"Teste"}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["AvocadoColors"][#2] &), 
   ImageSize -> 300], p1}]
```

[image]