# Plot Legends in 3D Parametric Plot with Color Function

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, legending, parametric-functions

I have two parametric space curves with different line styles plotted with `ParametricPlot3D`, with a `ColorFunction` applied. How do I get a plot legend to label the different lines? Without the `ColorFunction` `PlotLegends` works as normal, but with it, no legend is plotted.

Comment: I wonder, if it is a bug.

Comment: duplicate?: [PlotLegend disappears if Plot is used with ColorFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54517/125)

Comment: this is a  bug in versions 10+. It works in version 9 although the legend liness  do not have gradient coloring.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Legended`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html)

```
Legended[
 ParametricPlot3D[{
   {Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10},
   {Sin[2 u], Cos[3 u], u/5}},
  {u, 0, 20},
  PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[4]}, {Thick, Dashed}},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u}, Hue[u]]],
 LineLegend[
  {Thick, Dashed},
  {"{Sin[u],Cos[u],u/10}", "{Sin[2u],Cos[3u],u/5}"}]]
```

[image]